# Не работают InLine кнопки в python телеграмм бот

Tags: python

Бот не реагирует на кнопки. Только если вводить эту же информацию текстом

```
costables = ["200-400", "400-600", "600-700", "700"]
countryees = ['Египет', "ОАЭ", "Турция"]
days = ['5-7', '8-11', '12-15', '>16']
qwes = ['yes', 'no']

markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
for costable in costables:
    bth = types.InlineKeyboardButton(costable, callback_data=costable)
    markup.add(bth)

markup2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
for countryee in countryees:
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(countryee, callback_data=countryee)
    markup2.add(btn2)

markup3 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
for day in days:
    btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(day, callback_data=day)
    markup3.add(btn3)

country = ''
cost = ''
daysy = ''
dd = ''


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def start(message):
    if message.text == '/start':

        global country
        country = message.text
        user_id = message.from_user.id

        bot.send_message(user_id, """добро пожаловать в бот поиска горящих путевок. 
        для начала выбери цену в долларах""", reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, sto_it)
        username = message.from_user.username
        first_name = message.from_user.first_name
        last_name = message.from_user.last_name
        database.set_users(user_id, username, first_name, last_name)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'напиши /start что бы начать')



def sto_it(message):
    global cost
    cost = message.text
    costy = message.from_user.id

    bot.send_message(costy, 'теперь можем выбрать страну', reply_markup=markup2)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, markups)



def markups(message):
    global daysy
    daysy = message.text
    user_id = message.from_user.id

    bot.send_message(user_id, 'на сколько ночей хочешь уехать?', reply_markup=markup3)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, quest)


def quest(message):
    global dd
    dd = message.text
    markup4 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    for qwe in qwes:
        btn4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(qwe, callback_data=qwe)
        markup4.add(btn4)
    question = 'примерно за ' + str(cost) + ' хoчешь поехать в  ' + daysy + " на " + dd + ' дней?'
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=question, reply_markup=markup4)
```